# onMarkerClick listener drawing route and calculate distance

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-directions-api

On my map i want to make user when click on marker it be source and on click on another marker it be destination and drawing route calculating the distance 
my code didn't do that

I don't know what's wrong.

```
package com.example.gmapsapp;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;


public class Publicplaces extends FragmentActivity {
    private static final int GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
    public Marker marker;

    private static final double NASRCITY_LAT = 30.066108,
    NASRCITY_LNG =31.336184;
    private static final float DEFAULTZOOM = 13;

    GoogleMap map;
    ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;
    TextView tvDistanceDuration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (servicesOK()) {
            setContentView(R.layout.publicplaces);

            if (initMap()) {
                gotoLocation(NASRCITY_LAT, NASRCITY_LNG, DEFAULTZOOM);
                tvDistanceDuration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_distance_time);


            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Map not available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        // Initializing 
        markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

        // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment of the activity_main
        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
        map = fm.getMap();

        // Enable MyLocation Button in the Map
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);     
        map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

            public void onMarkerClick(LatLng point) {
                // Already two locations                
                if(markerPoints.size()>1){
                    markerPoints.clear();
                    map.clear();                    
                }

                // Adding new item to the ArrayList
                markerPoints.add(point);                

                // Creating MarkerOptions
                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

                // Setting the position of the marker
                options.position(point);

                 //int s = markerPoints.size();
                /** 
                 * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and
                 * for the end location, the color of marker is RED.
                 */
                if(markerPoints.size()==1){
                    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                }else if(markerPoints.size()==2){
                    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                }
                else{
                    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW));
                }


                // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
                map.addMarker(options);

                // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
                if(markerPoints.size() >= 2){                   
                    LatLng origin = markerPoints.get(0);
                    LatLng dest = markerPoints.get(1);
                    //LatLng next = markerPoints.get(2);

                    // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                    String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);                

                    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                    // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                    downloadTask.execute(url);

            }
        }

            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            };



        });

    }


    private boolean servicesOK() {
        int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)) {
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable, this, GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST);
            dialog.show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't connect to Google Play services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean initMap() {
        if (map == null) {
            SupportMapFragment mapFrag =
                    (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            map = mapFrag.getMap();
        }
        if (map != null){
            setupmap();
        }
        return (map != null);
    }

    private void setupmap() {
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(30.060953, 31.357416)).title("Ahmed Hendy Pharmacy")).showInfoWindow();       
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(30.056645, 31.354756)).title("Hasan Ali Pharmacy")).showInfoWindow();     
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(30.051739, 31.355807)).title("Osama El-Meleegi's Pharmacy")).showInfoWindow();        
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(30.054673, 31.346751)).title("Ezaby Pharmacies")).showInfoWindow();       
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(30.054711, 31.35052)).title("pharmacies drug")).showInfoWindow();     
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(30.045609, 31.361686)).title("Maraghy tenth district")).showInfoWindow();     
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(30.040400, 31.329994)).title("Anji Pharmacy")).showInfoWindow();      
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(30.064593, 31.339916)).title("Amr Pharmacy")).showInfoWindow();       
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(30.056538, 31.338285)).title("Pharmacies Delmar and Atallah")).showInfoWindow();      
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(30.061886, 31.333264)).title("J. Bakl Pharmacy")).showInfoWindow();       

    }

    private void gotoLocation(double lat, double lng,float zoom) {
        LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, zoom);
        map.moveCamera(update);
    }

    public void geoLocate(View v) throws IOException {
        hideSoftKeyboard(v);

        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String location = et.getText().toString();

        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
        List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
        Address add = list.get(0);
        String locality = add.getLocality();
        Toast.makeText(this, locality, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        double lat = add.getLatitude();
        double lng = add.getLongitude();

        gotoLocation(lat, lng, DEFAULTZOOM);

    }



    private void hideSoftKeyboard(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest ){

        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;

        //String str_next = "next="+next.latitude+","+next.longitude;



        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";         

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;


        return url;
    }

    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
                URL url = new URL(strUrl);

                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Connecting to url 
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Reading data from url 
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

                StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                        sb.append(line);
                }

                data = sb.toString();

                br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
                iStream.close();
                urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
     }



    // Fetches data from url passed
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{         

        // Downloading data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            try{
                // Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;        
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
        // doInBackground()
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
            super.onPostExecute(result);            

            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
            parserTask.execute(result);

        }       
    }

    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread        
        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject; 
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;                     

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

                // Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);    
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
            String distance = "";
            String duration = "";



            if(result.size()<1){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Points", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }


            // Traversing through all the routes
            for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
                points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                // Fetching i-th route
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                    HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j); 

                    if(j==0){   // Get distance from the list
                        distance = (String)point.get("distance");                       
                        continue;
                    }else if(j==1){ // Get duration from the list
                        duration = (String)point.get("duration");
                        continue;
                    }

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng); 

                    points.add(position);                       
                }

                // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                lineOptions.addAll(points);
                lineOptions.width(3);
                lineOptions.color(Color.RED);   

            }

            tvDistanceDuration.setText("Distance:"+distance + ", Duration:"+duration);

            // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
            map.addPolyline(lineOptions);                           
        }           
    }   


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }   
}
```

and this is json

```
package com.example.gmapsapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class DirectionsJSONParser {

    /** Receives a JSONObject and returns a list of lists containing latitude and longitude */
    public List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String,String>>>() ;
        JSONArray jRoutes = null;
        JSONArray jLegs = null;
        JSONArray jSteps = null;    
        JSONObject jDistance = null;
        JSONObject jDuration = null;

        try {           

            jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

            /** Traversing all routes */
            for(int i=0;i<jRoutes.length();i++){            
                jLegs = ( (JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");             

                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();              

                /** Traversing all legs */
                for(int j=0;j<jLegs.length();j++){

                    /** Getting distance from the json data */
                    jDistance = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONObject("distance");
                    HashMap<String, String> hmDistance = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hmDistance.put("distance", jDistance.getString("text"));

                    /** Getting duration from the json data */
                    jDuration = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONObject("duration");
                    HashMap<String, String> hmDuration = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hmDuration.put("duration", jDuration.getString("text"));

                    /** Adding distance object to the path */
                    path.add(hmDistance);

                    /** Adding duration object to the path */
                    path.add(hmDuration);                   


                    jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                    /** Traversing all steps */
                    for(int k=0;k<jSteps.length();k++){
                        String polyline = "";
                        polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                        List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);

                        /** Traversing all points */
                        for(int l=0;l<list.size();l++){
                            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            hm.put("lat", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).latitude) );
                            hm.put("lng", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).longitude) );
                            path.add(hm);                       
                        }                               
                    }                   
                }
                routes.add(path);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e){           
        }

        return routes;
    }   


    /**
     * Method to decode polyline points 
     * Courtesy : jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java 
     * */
    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                    (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }
}
```

Comment: Debug your code to see what data you have at which point on your logic. It's hard to guess where the error could be.
I reckon the problem is on the response and deserialization of the JSON response coming from directions API. 
Put a breakpoint on public List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject){ and tell us more.

Comment: i know how to add break point but where can i see what data i have ?

Comment: Android Studio or Eclipse? Both work similarly but it's been a while since I don't visit Eclipse. In Android Studio, when you debug your app, you can open the Debug view. View -> Tool Windows -> Debug. Inside of this view, select the "Debugger" tab. On the right side there is a list of the "Variables" and their state at the point in time of the breakpoint.

Comment: eclipse but i didn't know where is the comments and variables tap is empty

Comment: It will only show valuable data to your eyes when the execution is stopped on some breakpoint.

Comment: sir program not stopped :) it doesn't do the function

Comment: There you go. So, all ze breakpoints to the AsyncTasks.

Comment: If the breakpoint is in an AsyncTask, you may need to call `Debug.waitForDebugger`.

Comment: ok but can anyone help me i don't understand what this mean

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have 2 async task in one class? Its not a good technique to be followed, you can perform the download and parsing in the same async task thread. Those two threads may conflict and you have not written any syncronization code. Please add and see if that works.

Please have a look at this [tutorial](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/driving-route-from-my-location-to-destination-in-google-maps-android-api-v2/) for code implementation.

Hope that Helps!!

Comment: how the edit will be i want the code draw multiple route and this turorial drawing one route between two point only